# Question about Linux Scripting

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a command in linux that displays list of servers (6 in total) that are working in normal condition showing a "U" and multiple down/abnormal conditions (i.e, DN, DJ, UJ, UL etc).

Now I am wiring a script to monitor this. So far I have this down:

```
*A=command to get status of servers | grep 'U' |  awk '{print $1, $2}'|wc -l
if [ $A -lt 6 ];then
    "I need help with this section"
```

what I want to do is, if the "U" status of servers is less than 6 then I should grep whatever is in place of "U"

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Could you give an example of the output of the command? And what do you mean by "less than 6"?

Comment: Output displays 6 servers with their status as below:
'U  Server1 IP address 
U   Server2 IP address 
U   Server3 IP address 
DN Server4 IP address
U    Server5 IP address 
U   Server6 IP address'

So i have shown above the sample above with one of the server showing some other status. there can be several other in place of DN as i explained above. Oh and 6 is the total number of servers

Comment: Output displays 6 servers with their status as below: 'U Server1 IP address U Server2 IP address U Server3 IP address DN Server4 IP address U Server5 IP address U Server6 IP address' So i have shown above the sample above with one of the server showing some other status. there can be several other in place of DN as i explained above. Oh and 6 is the total number of servers and less than 6 would be when all 6 servers are not in "U" status.

Comment: Is the output of the command on one line or multiple lines? As I understand it in case of less than 6 servers having the `U` status you want to know which servers are still left in the `U` status. Right?

Comment: yes that is almost correct. I would like to trigger an email if one of the status on servers goes from "U" to anything else. While i already have the email alert part done, tested it by triggering an email on "U" status,  I am having trouble triggering alert when the status on server changes.

Comment: @TashfeenShahzad ok, I hope my answer below will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more dynamic approach try this one-liner:

```
s=$(get servers | grep -v ^U) || exit 0
```

This will get you the exceptional servers inside `$s` if there are any and exit otherwise.

**Important**: Replace `get servers` with your custom command to retrieve the server list.

Comment: I see so "^" sign "means not equal to"... this should indeed work if that is what i understand it is..Thanks

Comment: The `^` sign means that `U` has to be at the beginning of the line. Otherwise it won't match. On the other hand `-v` means that it should only print lines that do not match. If it works for you I would be happy if you mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, and using a file as example of the output of the command:

file

```
U Server1 IP address
U Server2 IP address
U Server3 IP address
DN Server4 IP address
U Server5 IP address
U Server6 IP address
```

Then:

```
servers=$(grep "^U" file | wc -l) # you don't need the awk part
[[ -z $servers || $servers -lt 6 ]] && grep -v "^U" file
```

Output:

```
DN Server4 IP address
```